# Introduction to stochastic control

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, stochastic-processes

I'm looking for an introductory text on stochastic control. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is also the order I would recommend them in (you will need to find used copies for the first, but that is an excellent text that is accessible and small in size).

- Stochastic Systems for Engineers: Modelling, Estimation and Control, John A. Borrie
- Introduction to Stochastic Control Theory (Dover Books on Electrical Engineering), 
  Karl Åström (can peruse on Amazon and price is great)
- Modeling, Analysis, Design, And Control Of Stochastic Systems: 2nd Ed., V. G. Kulkarni (can peruse on Amazon)
- Stationary Stochastic Processes for Scientists and Engineers, Georg Lindgren, Holger Rootzen, Maria Sandsten - this will help you to get your hands around SPs (can peruse on Amazon)

Answer (score 5):

I would also recommend the following two books of Kushner which provide a general and rigorous treatment of various topics in stochastic control theory including Lyapunov stability theory:

- H.J. Kushner, *Introduction to Stochastic Control*, Holt, Rinehart and Winston Editions, 1971.
- H.J. Kushner, *Stochastic stability and control,* Academic Press, New York, 1967.

From the point of view of stochastic programming, I would recommend the following references:

- A. Shapiro, D. Dentcheva and A.Ruszczynski, *Lectures on stochastic programming - modeling and theory*, MPS-SIAM series on optimization, 2009.
- D.P. Bertsekas and S.E. Shreve, Stochastic optimal control: the
  discrete time case, Academic press, 1978.

The lecture notes by Shapiro *et al.* offers a very well-written and comprehensible on stochastic programming. The book of Bertsekas and Shreve provides a very careful and rigorous discussion of dynamic programming for discrete-time stochastic optimal control problems.

If you are interested in the special case of discrete-time Markovian systems, I would recommend:

- O.L.V. Costa, M.D. Fragoso and R.P. Marques, *Discrete-time Markov Jump Linear Systems*, Springer 2005.

This books focuses on discrete-time Markov jump linear systems and discusses various notions of stochastic stability (e.g., mean square stability and almost sure convergence).

I would also recommend the book of Åström - I think it may be a good starting point.